# Why my recursion doesn't work in os.listdir(), it doesn't go to the lower level of a folder

Tags: python, linux

Below is my code, it seems like it didn't go into the recursion function.

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
import os

def rec(direc, pre):
        for item in os.listdir(direc):
                if os.path.isfile(item):
                        print pre + item + '\n'
                elif os.path.isdir(item):
                        print pre + item + '\n'
                        rec(direc + '/' + item, pre + '---')
rec('.', '-')
```

What I want from this code is to print out the directory hierarchy. What it does now is basically printing out everything in the current directory. It doesn't go into the folders in the current directory.

The output I want is like below: since D is a file in folder C

```
-B
-C
----D
-E
```

However it returns me:

```
-B
-C
-E
```

I tried every single commands, and they worked fine. However, when I put them together, I just didn't work properly. Another thing is that I know I can use os.walk to do this instead, but I just want to figure out why my code doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide debugging steps that you have taken to try to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Try printing the result of `os.path.isdir(item)` with the name of the file.  If your function is recursing, check the conditions required for recursion.

Comment: Please post your code as part of your question rather than a link. Also, include specific examples of what isn't working, and what you want to do, along with things you have already tried to debug your program. Stack Overflow isn't a debugging service, but if you have a specific problem, we can all learn by helping, as long as that question is well-asked.

Comment: Please paste your code as *text*, not images.

Comment: Do *not* post links to code, especially not links to *images of code*. Code is text. Post your code as formatted text in the question itself. The easiest way is to copy-and-paste into the editing window. Then highlight your code and press ctrl-k to automatically format it.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! Your question is hard to answer for a number of reasons.  Please read [ask] and [mcve] before resubmitting your question.

Comment: OP, you should use `os.walk` if you want to traverse recursively.

Comment: os.path.join(direc, item) should replace any concatenation of directories and files.  Also use it in place of item in the if os.path.isfile(item) and os.path.isdir(item) lines.  With os.path.join handling path concatenations, your code works fine.

Comment: I'd post the code to make it clearer, but you seem to be on-hold.

Comment: @AlanLeuthard Thank you so much! It just solved my problem! So my questions is string concatenation works different than os.path.join? And for the path of directories I should always using os.path rather than string concatenation?

Comment: os.path.join makes sure the pieces are put together properly for the system the script is running on.  You could do this with raw strings, but it can result in hard to find errors.

Comment: We don't post answers in questions here, nor add [solved] to titles. To that end I was going to move your answer-in-question to an answer below, but it looked identical to what Alan posted. If it was indeed different, please add a self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem stems from poorly thought out and/or formatted path strings.  Instead of concatenating raw strings, use os.path.join().  And make sure you're always passing absolute paths.  In that same vein, using string methods directly instead of "+" is often more efficient and usually more readable.  With those in mind, working code:

```
import os

def rec(direc, pre):
    for item in os.listdir(direc):
        checkpath = os.path.join(direc, item)
        if os.path.isfile(checkpath):
            print('{}{}\n'.format(pre, item))
        elif os.path.isdir(checkpath):
            print('{}{}\n'.format(pre, item))
            rec(checkpath, '{}---'.format(pre))

rec('.', '-')
```

Be warned: os.path.isdir() follows symbolic links, so you could end up in an infinite recursion situation.  Check for os.path.islink() if you don't need to follow links and want to avoid this situation.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

os.listdir() will return a list of filenames within a directory.

When you are calling the os.path.isfile() recursively it is literally just checking to see if ONLY the file name is a file. You likely want it to check the absolute path with os.path.isfile()

So consider changing:

```
is os.path.isfile(item):
```

to:

```
is os.path.isfile(pre+item):
```